Different Definitions of Limit Points.
I am trying to understand the topic of limit points.
I did see two different definitions of limit points.
Definition $1$:
Let $A$ be a subset of the real numbers. A point $x \in A$ is a limit point if every $\epsilon$ neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A\setminus\{x\}$.
Definition $2$:
Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence. We say $a$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$ if every $\epsilon$-neightborhood of $a$ contains infinatly many elements of the sequence. Sometimes limit points are also called accumulation points.
Question:
Regarding the definitions above, I am struggling to understand what a limit point is. Especially since both definitions define the term "limit point", but Definition $1$ is talking about limit points of a set while Definition $2$ speaks of limit points of a sequence. Also while doing some research on this topic I have found numerous sources that also call the limit point in Definition $1$ an "accumulation point".
Are those definitions just defining the same thing and consequently equivalent?
Or are they something different? I.e., is there a separation between the topic of "limit points of sequences" and "limit points of sets"?.
It would be appreciated if someone could give me some better insight on this topic.

You are correct that it would be preferable for these two concepts to have two different names.  In some beginning textbooks thre may be two different names.  (accumulation point, limit point, cluster point, etc.)  But, when you leave that book, you will have to be able to recognize them all.

You could call one a topological limit point and the other a sequential limit point.

@Steen82 Could you please explain why?

While both terms are related, they are not the same.
A good way to understanding limit points of sequences and sets, is to make oneself aware of the reason each of those terms was introduced and for what they are used.
Limit point of Sequences: 
Limit points of sequences emerge from the study of sequences.
By Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem we know that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.
And this is the context in where limit points of sequences appear.
Consider following Example:
Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be convergent to $a$ respectivly $b$.
If we define a new sequence $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, by letting it take the values of (a_n) and (b_n) in an alternating way (i.e. $c_1=a_1
,c_2=b_1,c_3=a_2,c_4=b_2,...$.)
Then (assuming $a \neq b$) the sequence $(c_n)$ does not converge.
But it still inherits a property in which we were interested while studying convergence of sequences. Infinetly many elements of the sequence $(c_n)$ get arbitrary close to $a$ respectivly $b$. One could say that the elements of the sequence "accumulate" around those two points. You can think of limit points of a squence as a generalization of limits of sequences.
There are two comon ways to define limit points of a sequence.
One uses convergence of subsequences while the other uses neighborhoods for description.
Definition (limit point of a sequence by using subsequences)
Suppose $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence. We say $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ if there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_j})_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $(x_{n_j})$ converges to $x$ as $j$ goes to $\infty$.
Definition (of limit points using neighborhoods)
Suppose $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence. We say $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ if every neighborhood of $x$, $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ contains infinitely many sequence elements of $(x_n)$.
Limit point of sets:
Limit points of a set, are points that can be approximated by a sequence that takes values in said set.
Consider the set $S=(0,1) \cup \{2\}$. We can find a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ whose elements are in $S$ such that $(a_n)$ converges to (for example) $1$, by letting $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$. While there exists no sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ whose elements are in $S$ that approximate $2$ (just take $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$).
Limit points of a set are closly related with the closedness of a set. As a set is closed if and only if it cointains all it's limit points.
There are also two comon ways to define limit point of a set.
Definition (limit point of a set using approximation)
Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. We say s is a limit point of the set $S$ if there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$  with elements in $S$ which converges to $s$ and whose elements are all $\neq s$.
Definition (limit point of a set using neighborhoods)
Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The point $s$ is a limit point of $S$ if every neighborhood V_{\epsilon}(s) contains at least one point $q \in S$, $q \neq s$.

In conclusion, given a limit point of a sequence we know that there exists a subsequence that converges to said point. And given a limit point of a set, we know that we can approximate said point from within the set.

If $x$ is a limit point of $A\subseteq \mathbb R$ in the sense of definition 1, then exists a sequence $(x_n)$, subject to $x_n\in A$ for all $n$ and $x$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ in the sense of definition 2, for you can select $x_n\in A$ with $|x_n-x|<\frac 1n$.
However, a limit point of $(x_n)$ in the sense of definition 2 may not be a limit point of the set $\{x_n: n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ in the sense of definition 1. A simple example is $x_n=0$ for all $n$ and $x=0$.
